# Firewall blocks access to grails repo

Tags: grails

`refresh dependencies` fails due to firewall+proxy combonation.

The corporate IT is not going to make an exception. I have found that I can do a recursive `wget` on the  [repo url](https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/) and generate duplicate their folder structure.

What can I do locally so that all developers can use this "mirror" by default?

If the above is not possible, where does grail usually put these files on a windows based installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding local repo to your BuildConfig and of course make it accessible over your LAN, or perhaps tell other devs to make their local cloned repos. The path to this local repo could be ENVARIONMENT_VARIABLE, too (that makes it fully customizable)

```
repositories {
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo('/path/to/my-local-maven-repo')
}
```

http://jdpgrailsdev.github.io/blog/2014/02/10/grails_maven_local_repo.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here.

First, if it's just a normal proxy than you can configure grails to utilise it. Take note of the following grails commands:

- [grails add-proxy](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/ref/Command%20Line/add-proxy.html)
- [grails set-proxy](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/ref/Command%20Line/set-proxy.html)

These in turn will establish a file in your home directory in `.grails` called `ProxySettings.groovy` (i.e. `~/.grails/ProxySettings`) that is then used by all grails commands for all projects.

However, if you're behind a Microsoft NTLM proxy (as I am) then I'd suggest still doing the above by making use of [Java NTLM Proxy](http://java-ntlm-proxy.sourceforge.net/).

(Keep in mind though, that the grails wrapper does not use the above `ProxySettings.groovy` and then you need to use the standard JAVA_OPTS of `-Dhttp.proxyPort`, `-Dhttp.proxyHost`, etc.)

But I appreciate maybe you've done all that and you still want to avoid the proxy. I'd suggest the next solution - and one that should be considered anyway - is setting up a corporate/internal Maven repository server with something like Artifactory or Nexus.

Lastly, there is the instruction from MamyKryzysKryzysKryzys with using `mavenRepo( <localPath> )`. [More info](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/guide/conf.html#dependencyRepositories) on that is available in the grails doco.

Finally, to address your question of "where does grail usually put these files". Under the hood grails is simply using maven so it's stored in your [normal maven local repo](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) which is `~/.m2/repository`.

Good luck! Proxies make things hard, but once you figure your solution it's a thing of the past. Personally, we now use a combination of the Java NTLM Proxy and an internal Artifactory server.